# Scroll to Next DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a page template like this:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <header class="header-5">
        <div class="container">
           content
        </div>
        <div class="background"></div>
    </header>

<section class="content-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
            content
            <a class="control-btn" href="#"> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
```

When `<a class="control-btn" href="#"> </a>` is clicked, I want it to scroll to the last `<div class="container">` (the last line in the code snippet).

With this jQuery, it scrolls to the first `div.container` (toward the top of the snippet):

```
 $('.control-btn').on('click', function() {
        $.scrollTo($(".container"), {
            axis : 'y',
            duration : 500
        });
        return false;
    });
```

How can I get it to scroll to the **next** `div.container` (the last one in my code example)?

Note: There are other `div.container` elements further down -- this isn't the "last" one on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.control-btn').on('click', function () {
    var ele = $(this).closest("section").find(".container");
    // this will search within the section
    $("html, body").animate({
         scrollTop: $(ele).offset().top
    }, 100);
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kihum/1/edit)**