# Jquery arrow keys navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to programming in jquery. What i want to do is to make the page scroll down to the next "container" class everytime i press arrow down, and reverse with arrow up. I have tried googling a lot, but i couldn't seem to find a manageable solution.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="containers">
    <div class="boxed" class="container">
        <p class="overskrift1">Internet Kriminalitet</p>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxed2" class="container">

    </div>
</div>
```

I want the arrow keys to navigate between the different containers.

*EDIT*

This is probably the best jquery code i have so far:

```
$('body').on('keypress'), (function () {
var ele = $(this).closest("section").find(".container");
$("body").animate({
scrollTop: $(ele).offset().top
                }, 100);
return false;
```

});

Thank you

- Morten

Comment: What jQuery code have you tried up to this point?

Comment: uh, i've tried lurking around on stackoverflow and tried to integrate ex. this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226823/scroll-to-next-div-using-jquery and some others than i dont even remember at this point

Comment: Showing where your code is at this point will give us insight into the level of detail we need to go into to give an answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you have to do is:

- put an event on the body that listen to [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)
- switch the key to get which arrow was pressed. (37, 38, 39, 40  => left, up, right down).
- when the key is pressed you have to animate the page scrollTop to the element top.

Something like:

```
var containers = $('.container');
var currentContainer = containers.get(0);
$('body').on('keydown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.which);
    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
            // left
            break;

        case 38:
            // up
            currentContainer = currentContainer.prev();
            break;

        case 39:
            // right
            break;

        case 40:
            // down
            currentContainer = currentContainer.next();
            break;

        default:
            return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: currentContainer.getPosition().top + 'px'
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9qhgsysg/1/

Comment: I have tried to fiddle around with a similiar code, I'll give it a try, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this plugin https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Then the following script

```
$(function() {

    function scroll(direction) {

        var scroll, i,
            positions = [],
            here = $(window).scrollTop(),
            collection = $('.container');

        collection.each(function() {
            positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'], 10));
        });

        for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) {
                scroll = collection.get(i);
                break;
            }
            if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) {
                scroll = collection.get(i - 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (scroll) {
            $.scrollTo(scroll, {
                duration: 600
            });
        }

        return false;
    }

    $("#next,#prev").click(function() {
        return scroll($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $(".scrollto").click(function() {
        $.scrollTo($($(this).attr("href")), {
            duration: 600
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Where the next and prev ids both have a class of .scrollto.

The above js allows you to create a fixed position next/prev nav that persists and allows you to scroll up or down to closest container.

```
<div class="toolbar">
 <a id="next" class="scrollto">Next</a>
 <a id="prev" class="scrollto">Prev</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean with "Where the next and prev ids both have a class of .scrollto"? I'm sorry if i sound retarded :/

Comment: Hmmm, the thing is, i need to use my arrow keys, not click on buttons on the website.

Comment: Sorry - I did notice that after posting last. If you like where I'm going with this then I can add arrow keys. Just let me know.

Comment: That'd be great yeah :)